# "MySQL server has gone away" error after long idle

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I know this issue is not a new one on SO but I'm unable to find a solution. Whenever I return to my desk after leaving my app running overnight, I get a `MySQL server has gone away` error that persists until I restart my uwsgi service. I've already done the following:

- `pool_recycle=`some really large number in my `create_engine()` call
- Added a `ping_connection()` after a `@event.listens_for()` decorator (and I can't use `pool_pre_ping` - that breaks my `create_engine()` call)
- in `/etc/my.cnf` I added `wait_timeout` and `interactive_timeout` params with large values

but nothing has had any effect.

Comment: is the value of `pool_recycle` less than the `timeout` value?

Comment: They are identical to each other. I have them set to one week.

Comment: set it to lower, you need to refresh the session `before` timeout

Comment: I did that and I did not see the error up until this point. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the sqlalchemy doc located [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html#pool-setting-recycle), the *pool_recycle* feature is what you are looking for.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine("mysql://scott:tiger@localhost/test", pool_recycle=28700)
```

Set *pool_recycle* to a value < *wait_timeout* in your mysql configuration file *my.cnf*

MySQL default *wait_time* is 28800 (8 hrs)

Dont forget to restart your services (i.e. mysql, etc) if you do modify the conf files